# How to connect Yoroi to testnet?

Tags: wallet, yoroi, testnet

I already have a testnet `cardano-node` running on my machine. How can I connect Yoroi there? Is the hetwork hardcoded in the wallet or I'm missing some advanced settings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to install [Yoroi Nightly](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/yoroi-nightly/poonlenmfdfbjfeeballhiibknlknepo?hl=en&authuser=0).